# Duplicate of legends are Produced in ng2 chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

Multiple legend of same data labels are produced but I only need single label for each dataset.

```
 this.BarChartLabels = []
    this.BarChartData = []
    this.Service.getCount().subscribe(data => {
             let len =data.length;           
             for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
              this.BarChartLabels.push(data[i].date) var color1=['red','blue','green']
      var color=0  
              for(let j=0;j<data[i].Counters.length;j++)
              {
                const arr = Array(len).fill(0);
                arr[i] = data[i].Counters[j].count; 
               this.BarChartData.push({label:data[i].Counters[j].Name, data: arr, backgroundColor:color}) 
color++;
              }            
             }                        
    })
```

Here I am getting a multi level array so I used for loop to retrieve it  As a result my legend is taking same data multiple times. Is there any way by which could I produce a single data for legend.

Answer (score 0):

The legend has a filter parameter which you can use to hide same labels: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration

EDIT:
Sample to filter out all duplicates: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/vto6z3g4/15/

```
options: {
    legend: {
        labels: {
        filter: (legendItem,chartData) => {
          return !(chartData.labels.indexOf(legendItem.text) < legendItem.index);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: so how could I use this function (if possible could you give me an example?) and how could i check that multiple data are there? @LeeLenalee

Comment: Here you have an example that hides all the legends that have a zero value I made a while back, https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/vto6z3g4/11/. If you want to hide duplicate labels you will have to get the label index from legendItem and see if there is no duplicate label before it from the whole labels array which is in chartData

Comment: As i am new to this progaramming(if possible) could you please help me out tell me how could i get label from index and then check for duplicate from label array in chart data ? Here in my chart data labels I have date and whereas the problem is with the displaying of label of chartdatasets as multiple data of same chartdataset label are obtained  @LeeLenalee